# Saboteur 2 - Restrictions on playing "trapped!" in the end of the round

Tags: saboteur-2

Are there any in-game restrictions on playing the trapped! and the tool-breaking cards in the end of the round? For example, can I play the trapped card as my last one on a player who has no more cards?

Answer (score 1):

In the [rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/saboteur/saboteur2-game-rules.php) there are no special restrictions for the new action cards.

In the normal gameplay:

> When it is your turn, you have to take one of the four following
> actions:
>
> 1. Place a path card in the tunnel maze then draw 1 card.
> 2. Play an action card then draw 1 card.
> 3. Discard two cards from your hand to remove a card in front of you then draw 1 card.
> 4. Pass and discard 1-3 face-down cards from your hand then draw 1-3 cards.
>
> Then your turn is over and it's the next player's turn.

There is also no restriction mentioned for the trapped card:

> Trapped! (3 in the game)
>
> Play this card face-up in front of another player of your choice. This
> player is trapped and cannot play any more path cards. If a player is
> trapped when the round ends, they don't get counted as one of the
> winners and don't get a cut of the treasure.

So yes you can play an trapped card on a player that has no cards in hand. It literally traps the player, but he or she can be rescued by another player using the "Free at last!" card.